# Nearby wifi networks causing notification

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, notifications

I am using a brand new Blu R1 HD android phone running 6.0.

On my way to work this morning I was listening to a podcast over bluetooth in my car.

Every once in a while a notifcation would sound on the stereo. I would open my phone and it would say "wifi networks nearby".

I have never experienced this on an Android phone.

How can i disable notifications sounding when a nearby wifi network is detected (barring shutting down the wifi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Wi-Fi -> (3-dot menu near top right corner) -> Advanced

Turn OFF **Network Notifications**

[image: Wi-Fi Advanced Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck or toggle *notify when public network available* (from settings> WiFi> advanced)- that may be the reason

Comment: My thought as well. Alternatively (and that should work for sure): disable WiFi whenever you don't use it anyway. There are lots of [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) apps to help you with that. I e.g. use [Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info), and have it turn off WiFi whenever I leave home – and turn it back on when I return.