# Disable WiFi-discovery notifications on the LG G6

Tags: notifications, lg

How does one turn off "WiFi Network Available" notifications on the LG G6? It's a mite spammy in cities.

I could turn off notifications for the app entirely, but that would hide "sign in" and "incorrect password" notifications.

This question is LG G6 specific because its interface does not admit [the more general solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168647/nearby-wifi-networks-causing-notification).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nearby wifi networks causing notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168647/nearby-wifi-networks-causing-notification)

Comment: Does not apply. The LG G6 interface does not have that setting in the same place.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Advanced menu under Settings > Wi-Fi?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your question?